# What hardware do I need to capture live video from my Nikon D3300 DSLR directly into Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: mac, mojave, hardware, video

Basically, I would like to use my Nikon D3300 DSLR as a webcam. I want to be able to see the video in my Mac as I record. What hardware would I need to use to accomplish this?

Comment: What ports are on your Nikon?

Comment: Which model is it? The 3xxx & 5xxx cannot do this at all.

Comment: The ports are HDMI (I think it actually is a HDMI mini) and A/V Out Heres a picture: https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/431746.image0.jpg

Comment: It is a Nikon D3300

Comment: Then it can't be done. You can get live video into the Mac using Camera Control Pro 2 [approx $£€ 150], but you can't hand that off to any other process.

Comment: https://www.video-stitch.com/how-to-use-dslr-as-webcam/ recommends http://camtwiststudio.com/download/ but the software hasn't seen upgrades for a while and requires input via USB. And there are things like https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/cam-link-4k, but D3300 isn't supported.

Comment: Workaround - which is how I do it with my D5500 [same limitation as yours] is record audio & video separately, just using a clap-sync, then import & line up to the clap. Old-school & a bit clunky in comparison, but it works 'just like in the movies';) Video is recorded to the camera's SD, audio from a separate mic rig into Cubase [though audacity would do at a push] I use Camera Control to get the picture settings & use as a monitor, but the camera itself has to do the take, then transfer.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It's a great idea. Thank you.